# Importing different solidity verion in your contract

Tags: solidity, uniswap, hardhat, solidity-0.8.x, uniswapv3

I am trying to import uniswap v3 contracts, which uses version 0.7.6 in my contract that uses 0.8.1. for fetching the TWAP price.
am importing these two :

```
import "@uniswap/v3-core/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV3Factory.sol";
import "@uniswap/v3-periphery/contracts/libraries/OracleLibrary.sol";
```

I am getting thes errors

```
Error HH606: The project cannot be compiled, see reasons below.

These files import other files that use a different and incompatible version of Solidity:
```

I have tried -

- Added compiler verion in hardhat config.

I have found this [Hardhat FAQ](https://hackmd.io/@fvictorio/a-hardhat-faq#The-project-cannot-be-compiled-HH606)

which states that

```
you might have a contract with pragma version ^0.7.0 that imports a contract with ^0.6.0. This can never be compiled. Pragma versions indicate which subset of the compiler versions can be used, and if two pragma versions don’t intersect (like in this example), then the files cannot be compiled. Period.
```

Is there anyway how i can make this work, without downgrading my custom contracts, because that is not an option right now.

Comment: Uniswap provides a Solidity v0.8 implementation on the [0.8](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-core/tree/0.8) branch. Also see this [discussion](https://github.com/paulrberg/prb-math/discussions/104) in my PRBMath project's repository involving a user who tried to use PRBMath (v0.8) with Uniswap (v0.7).

Comment: Thank you refering this have helped

Comment: I ended up copying the uniswap V3 contracts in my own repo, which worked but with a hasle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Uniswaps ^0.8.0 contracts.
You can find them here easily: https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-core/tree/0.8

Comment: Thank  you, I have copied their codes and used it in my contracts instead of importing from npm packages.

Answer (score 0):

You can compile contracts with multiple versions of Solidity by setting in the `hardhat.config.js` file. Here is the example:

```
module.exports = {
    solidity: {
        compilers: [
            {
                version: "0.7.6",
            },
            {
                version: "0.8.1",
            },
       ],
   },
};
```

You can read more about compiling multiple versions in Hardhat [here](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/advanced/multiple-solidity-versions).

Comment: This won't work as I am importing v7 code in my v8 contract.

as mention in [here]( https://hackmd.io/@fvictorio/a-hardhat-faq#The-project-cannot-be-compiled-HH606)